# После переворота экрана в 100vh появляется скролл на Iphone. В чем дело?

Tags: javascript, html, css, yandex-maps-api, адаптивная-верстка

недавно столкнулся с проблемой на айфонах и андройдах: экран в 100vh все равно скроллился, долго искал решение, в итоге нашел такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так вот, проблема исчезла на айфоне и андройде. Но появилась следующая, при перевороте экрана все работает отлично. Но стоит еще раз перевернуть экран и листнуть вниз, появляется ненужный скролл, потом сразу исчезает. И в итоге, часть контента остается сверху, а внизу остается белая пустая полоса. Скажите, пожалуйста, может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой? Есть ли варианты ее решения, кроссбраузерные?

Вот после переворота:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.s при еще раз повороте проблема исчезает, но хотелось бы, чтоб она вообще не возникала
Заранее спасибо всем, кто ответит. Я ценю любую поддержку

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Куда точнее? Что именно не понятно? Хочу устранить эту проблему, понять, почему возникает

Comment: @DanilGallyamshin  сталкивался с похожим. в итоге решил это `position: fixed; height: 100%` таким образом работает нормально. но это если подходит fixed

Comment: Соглашусь с предыдущим комментарием. Если нужна карта Яндекс, попробуйте отказаться от указания размеров через относительные единицы измерения vh, vw, vmin, vmax, отдав предпочтение более классическим методам.

Comment: @fanfer спасибо, попробую

Comment: @YaCor' а не подскажете как в другом случае сделать карту на всю оставшуюся высоту? Может сталкивались? Просто у меня хедер определенный высоты, а карту без vh и то с решением проблемы через js, сделать не могу

Comment: Конкретных примеров не подскажу. Знаю только, что карты с таким подходом к установке размера ведут себя непредсказуемо. У вас скролл появляется, а у кого-то балуны уползают за границу карты, когда она не на всю vw ширину. Карты вроде стабильно работают, когда размеры определены фиксированно, либо вписаны на 100% в фиксированный родительский блок. Как его размеры удобно задать в вашем сценарии без использования vh не подскажу. Быть может кто другой тут что посоветует.

Comment: @YaCor' Хорошо, все равно спасибо за наводки!

Answer (score 2):

При изменении размеров карты надо вызывать `map.container.fitToViewport()`.
https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/map.Container.html#method_detail__fitToViewport